# Conservation of momentum in superfluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, viscosity, superfluidity

Superfluids such as $^4\text{He}$ under Lambda temperature displays properties of superfluids, having nearly $0$ viscosity. This allows the fluid to pass through space packed with fine powders that regular fluids cannot pass through.

However, I'm curious as to how momentum is conserved in atomic level of such superfluids. Does zero viscosity means all collisions are perfectly elastic, thus no kinetic energy is lost as thermal energy? If so what gives such property? If not, what could explain the conservation of momentum?

Comment: If you are asking for the theory of superfluids, you should easily find it in textbooks or on the internet. Also, what relation does conservation of momentum has even if the collisions are perfectly elastic?

Comment: Since superfluidity is a quantum effect, thinking in terms of "collisions" may not be helpful here. Also, in any case, momentum is conserved regardless of whether collisions are elastic or inelastic.

Comment: Says wikipedia: "Despite having no viscosity, turbulence is possible in a superfluid. This was first suggested theoretically by Richard Feynman in 1955,[1] and was soon found experimentally." R.P. Feynman (1955). "Application of quantum mechanics to liquid helium". II. Progress in Low Temperature Physics. 1.